# Check if someone is waiting in wait() / notify()

Tags: java, concurrency

Is it possible to check if at least one thread is waiting before calling `notifyAll()`?

I have a queue where a chef puts dishes in, whereas people come and get that dishes. If the cook puts dishes in the empty queue, the people must be notified that they can come (they are set to `wait()` if the queue is empty and they want to get a dish).

So that method begins with

```
public synchronized void put(String[] dishes){
    if(dishesQueue.size() == 0){
        notifyAll();
    }
    (...)
}
```

But now the problem is that when the chef puts in dishes for the first time, the queue is empty, but no people are waiting yet, so I get an `java.lang.IllegalMonitorStateException`. Is there a way to check first if there are threads waiting, and if yes, `notifyAll()`? Or have I use some "tricky" solution with a `boolean firstTime` or something?

Additionally for understanding, is it right that even if only the chef calls `put(...)`, the method must be `synchronized` too because it operates with the dishesQueue, which is also manipulated by the `get()` method?

Comment: No, you shouldn't get an exception just because of that. You can call `notifyAll` regardless of whether anything's waiting. Please show a short but complete program which demonstrates the problem.

Comment: The exception you report would be thrown only if you called `notifyAll` without owning the monitor of the target object. This is clearly not the case in your code sample.

Comment: Second thing, you probably don't have a good reason to fiddle with the clunky *wait-notify* mechanism. There are concurrent queues at your disposal that only require you to call their methods, no synchronizing, no wait-loops, etc.

Comment: Check thread state for a waiting thread.